# QuickBlox - Video and Audio is not working when accepting a video call

Tags: swift, audio, video, webrtc, quickblox

I tried to implement quickblox - video chat function into my ios app with Swift3. After test, I could call the opponent and the opponent could accept the call, but there is not video and audio show up. I confirmed the functions "receivedRemoteVideoTrack" and "receivedRemoteAudioTrack" are executed, but still no audio and video in the call. Could anyone advise?
Thank you very much!

I have uploaded the demo project onto Github, please change auth key if you want to run it. Please let me know if there is any information I lost, and all your comments are appreciated. Thank you!

https://github.com/nick1ee/QuickBloxDemo_2

I have enclosed the logs as below.

https://github.com/nick1ee/QuickBloxDemo_2/blob/master/Logs

Comment: Hello, Sorry for message Nick are you able to fix this issue and the demo link not available.

Comment: Sorry Seggy, I forgot to update the solution for this issue. All you need to do is to capture video and audio source before making a call via webrtc, then both features will work normally.

Comment: its ohk, recently i done video and audio call on quickblox-webrtc swift 3 that's why posted comment.